# Why a number outside ascii range is being printed?

Tags: c++, ascii

Here is my code which take numbers as input and show the char of the output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int A[1000];

int main()
{

    int ln=0,min = 99999999;
    while(!cin.eof())
    {
        A[ln]=0;
        for(int i=0;i<3;++i)
        {
            int x;
            cin>>x;
            A[ln]+=x;
        }
        if(A[ln]<=min)
            min = A[ln];
        ++ln;
    }

    char buffer[2049];
    for(int j=0;j<ln-1;++j)
    {
        int x = A[j] - 250;
        cout<<x<<endl;
        if(x<32)
            cout<<x<<" here goes non-printable ascii"<<endl;
        if(x>127)
            cout<<x<<"here goes non-printable ascii"<<endl;
        buffer[j] = x;
    }

    buffer[ln-1] = 0;
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

Now printable Ascii value is between 32 and 127. But, when I give the program input`296 294 255 268 313 278 311 270 290 305 322 252 276 286 301 305 264 301 251 269 274 311` I have the following output,

```
595
595here goes non-printable ascii
609
609here goes non-printable ascii
621
621here goes non-printable ascii
629
629here goes non-printable ascii
613
613here goes non-printable ascii
620
620here goes non-printable ascii
544
544here goes non-printable ascii
Samuel
```

But at last it is printing "Samuel" So , what is the problem??

Comment: Because 296 + 294 + 255 - 250 = 595, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you are typecasting the char, The least significant byte is stored only, and that is least significant byte of `595` is `1010011` which is ASCII `83`.

Comment: There are no typecasts in this code. There is an **implicit conversion** when the `int` value is stored into the `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing integers not chars.
chars have values in the range [-128, 127]. unsigned char is in the range [0,255]. Convert the integer to char or unsigned char before printing.

```
cout << (char)x << endl;
```

Comment: That is not my question, I know, but Ascii of S is 83 , so why cout<<(char)595<<endl; would print S too?

Comment: converting to char crops the MSB (top 3 bytes of the int). cout's operator << works differnt when getting chars and ints. Actually it's 2 different functions.